# Project Facets is missing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to run my project on server. But this option is missed in Run as.

[image]

When I googled the problem I found this article as solution. http://consistentcoder.com/configure-run-on-server-option-on-a-maven-project-on-eclipse-ide.
But the problem is that I missed Project Facets option is missed in the properties.

[image]

I'm new one for Eclipse. Please help me to overcome this issue. If there are any other way to ruun this on server please leave your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have the server tools from the Web Tools Platform installed. https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F